# Image capture always returns result code of 0 and makes the Gallery stop

Tags: java, android

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) line for line on the android site.  I am attempting to take a picture, save it, and then retrieve it later.  But every time I take the picture and hit <kbd>okay</kbd> I get the message "***Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped.***"  and the result code is returning as 0, unsurprisingly.  I test to make sure the storage is read and writable so I'm not sure where the issue is.

For reference I am testing on Android version: 4.4.2, minSdkVersion: 15, targetSdkVersion: 24.

file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.lamelemon.arbitrary/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
```

Acitivity

```
private void dispatchCapturePictureIntent() {
    Intent capturePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (capturePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

               Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.lamelemon.arbitrary.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                capturePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(capturePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String test;
    String test2;

    if(isExternalStorageReadable()){test = "Read true";}
    else{test = "Read false";}

    if(isExternalStorageWritable()){test2 = "Write true";}
    else{test2 = "Write false";}

    Log.e("Readable", test);
    Log.e("Writable", test2);
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}


/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 4.4 does not automatically grant the other app any access to your `ContentProvider`. Their sample only works on Android 5.0+, and even that relies on undocumented behavior on the part of the `Intent` class.

You need to call `addFlags()` on the `Intent` to grant write access, as is demonstrated in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider). The core chunk of code is explained in greater detail in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html), as granting permissions for a `Uri` in an `Intent` extra is not that easy.

So, given an `Intent` named `i` and a `Uri` named `outputUri`, we have:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
  }
  else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    ClipData clip=
      ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

    i.setClipData(clip);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
  }
  else {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
      getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
      String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
      grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
  }
```

Technically, the first case (the simple call to `addFlags()`) is superfluous, but since this behavior is undocumented, I prefer to manually add the flag to be certain.

Comment: The blog post, while difficult to understand for a first time android developer, was very informative.  Thank you!